# R and xml2: how to read text that is not in children nodes and read information even if node is missing

Tags: r, xpath, xml2

I use `R` and it's package `xml2` to parse an `html` document. I extracted a piece of `html` file, which looks like this:

```
text <- ('<div>
<p><span class="number">1</span>First&nbsp;<span class="small-accent">previous</span></p>
<p><span class="number">2</span>Second&nbsp;<span class="accent">current</span></p>
<p><span class="number">3</span>Third&nbsp;</p>
<p><span class="number">4</span>Fourth&nbsp;<span class="small-accent">last</span> A</p>
</div>')
```

And my goal is to extract information from the text and to convert it into data frame, which looks like this one:

```
  number      label   text_of_accent   type_of_accent
1      1      First         previous     small-accent
2      2     Second          current           accent
3      3      Third                                  
4      4   Fourth A             last     small-accent
```

I tried the following code:

```
library(xml2)
library(magrittr)

html_1 <- text %>% 
    read_html() %>% 
    xml_find_all( "//span[@class='number']")  

number <- html_1 %>% xml_text()

label  <- html_1 %>%
    xml_parent() %>% 
    xml_text(trim = TRUE)

text_of_accent <- html_1 %>%
    xml_siblings() %>% 
    xml_text()

type_of_accent <- html_1 %>% 
    xml_siblings() %>%
    xml_attr("class")
```

Unfortunately, `label`, `text_of_accent`, `type_of_accent` are not extracted as I expect:

```
label
[1] "1First previous" "2Second current" "3Third"          "4Fourth last A" 

text_of_accent
[1] "previous" "current"  "last" 

type_of_accent
[1] "small-accent" "accent"       "small-accent"
```

Is it possible to achieve my goal with just `xml2` or I need some additional tools? At least is it possible to extract pieces of text for `label`?

Comment: I am guessing that logically, if you know what fields to expect, you use iterate over the parent nodes and populate the children with NULL unless found. Does that help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It can be done with `xml2`, the reason your `label` messed up is `xml_text()` finds out all the texts including the current node and its children nodes, to avoid this, you can use xpath `text()` to locate the text for the current node firstly, then extract it and also you need to check if some nodes exist and handle the missing cases properly:

```
# read in text as html and extract all p nodes as a list
lst <- read_html(text) %>% xml_find_all("//p")

lapply(lst, function(node) {
    # find the first span
    first_span_node = xml_find_first(node, "./span[@class='number']")

    number = xml_text(first_span_node, trim = TRUE)

    # use the text() to find out text nodes from the current position
    label = paste0(xml_text(xml_find_all(node, "./text()")), collapse = " ")

    # find the second span
    accent_node = xml_find_first(first_span_node, "./following-sibling::span")

    # check if the second span exists
    if(length(accent_node) != 0) {
        text_of_accent = xml_text(xml_find_first(accent_node, "./text()"))
        type_of_accent = xml_text(xml_find_first(accent_node, "./@class"))    
    } else {
        text_of_accent = ""
        type_of_accent = ""
    }

    c(number = number, label = label, 
      text_of_accent = text_of_accent, 
      type_of_accent = type_of_accent)
}) %>% 
do.call(rbind, .) %>% as.data.frame()


#  number     label text_of_accent type_of_accent
#1      1    First        previous   small-accent
#2      2   Second         current         accent
#3      3    Third                               
#4      4 Fourth  A           last   small-accent
```

Comment: Brilliant solution :)